# UIDatePicker input field misaligns

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I inherited an iOS project written in Swift 4.2, that uses a `UIDatePicker` as the input view of a text field:

```swift
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.maximumDate = Date()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
datePicker.date = self.someDate
someTextField.inputView = datePicker
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

^ The code snippet above is slightly obfuscated, but shows the basic logic.

This is the result of the input view:

[image]

I've tried to manually align the input view by setting auto layout constraints:

```swift
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.maximumDate = Date()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
datePicker.date = self.someDate
datePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
datePicker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
datePicker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
datePicker.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
someTextField.inputView = datePicker
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

However, this only results in the program crashing.

What should I do to make the input view align properly on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue from inheriting an iOS project. I changed the type of picker to wheels to return the pre iOS 14 look of the picker and to fit in with the original design.

```
picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
```